# HTML divs overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm still learning html and css, trying to figure out how everything works, without much coding experience. I want a rectangular box extending across the top, a rectangular box extending downward on the left, and a square box in the corner of the two. Right now, when I resize the window, my corner div overlaps with the top div, and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated!

HTML:

```
.topbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 89%;
}

.sidebar {
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:fixed;
    border:solid 1px #000;
    width:80px;
    left: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    background-color: #babcbf;
    padding:2px;
}

.cornerBox {
  overflow:hidden;
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  top:10vh;
  right:12vw;
  position:absolute;
  display:fixed;
}
```

Comment: thats css what you have mentioned

Comment: It is because of `fixed` and `absolute` positioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you avoided absolute/fixed positioning for stuff like this. You can use [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

There's a series of videos I found on CSS grid [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-slCsOrLcc&list=PLu8EoSxDXHP5CIFvt9-ze3IngcdAc2xKG&index=2) - not my videos, but they're really good.

```css
:root {
  /* change this to the desired min sidebar width */
  --sidebar-min-width: 150px;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(var(--sidebar-min-width), 25%) 1fr;
}

.header {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  background-color: #babcbf;
}

.content {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">header</header>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar sidebar </div>
    <div class="content">content content content content content content content content content content </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful.